# como instalar imagemagick no macintosh ( Xampp)

Tags: php, xampp, instalador, osx, imagemagick

Estava a tentar instalar o imagemagick no mac, abri o terminal  e executei o seguinte comando

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)".
```

depois verifiquei

```
brew install imagemagick

brew install php56-imagick
```

Mas quando abro o php info não aparece nada a respeito

Também tentei no terminal

```
php -m
```

Mas também nao aparece e reiniciei o apache

Localização da instalação: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles`

Usando:

- PHP Version 5.6.30
- Mac OSX El captain

Ao tentar isto:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
chmod -R 0777 /tmp
./pecl install imagick
```

> WARNING: configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/install" is not
>   writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to
>   avoid this warning WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its
>   protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>   downloading imagick-3.4.3.tgz ... Starting to download
>   imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
>   ...................................................done: 245,410 bytes
>   ERROR: failed to mkdir /tmp/pear/install/imagick.

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.30 osx el captain

Comment: nao sei o que queres dizer com a terceira

Comment: Apache 2.0 Handler é isto ?

Comment: Pronto editei a pergunta, não vou tentar responder porque não tenho um Mac aqui para poder efetuar todos testes, mas no escritório tenho um, se ninguém responder até segunda eu respondo ;)

Comment: alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Caso possua o Homebrew, execute isso no console command:

Instale o imagemagick caso não esteja instalado:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

A instalação do imagemagick NÃO INCLUI a library para o PHP. Portanto, instale a library específica do PHP.

```
brew install php-imagick
```

Reinicie o Apache e rode o `phpinfo()` ou, no console execute `php -m` para ver a lista de módulos carregados.

## Importante

Esteja ciente que o comando que contém `php-imagick` pode ter outra nomenclatura, por exemplo, `php5-imagick`. Depende como está instalado o PHP no seu ambiente. Um modo prático para saber o nome do pacote PHP, é usando o próprio brew command.

Pode fazer isso:

```
brew list php
```

Alternativamente tente isso, caso o anterior não retorne resultados:

```
brew search php
```

No ambiente OSX (mac), o PHP é geralmente nomeado em conjunto com a versão. Exemplo, se for versão 5.4.qualquer_coisa, é provável que será php54. Portanto o comando para instalar a library seria assim:

```
brew install php54-imagick
```

Obviamente, isso é apenas um exemplo. Antes de invocar a instalação, certifique-se qual o nome correto, então aplique-o ao comando de instalação.

**Alternativamente** pode instalar direto dos sources. Mas é uma tarefa que exige muitos detalhes e pode gerar problemas com conflitos entre bibliotecas e dependências. Um gerenciador de pacotes como o Homebrew simplifica esse trabalho.

## Instalando via PEAR/PECL

Caso o pacote XAMP possua o binário do pecl, acesse o diretório:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

Execute:

Para instalar o imagick:

```
./pecl install imagick
```

Após isso, verifique se no php.ini foi adicionado a extensão corretamente. Deve haver algo assim:

```
extension=imagick.so
```

Se não encontrar, adicione manualmente. Mas obviamente, o arquivo imagick.so deve existir, caso contrário o apache pode não iniciar.

Após isso, reinicie o Apache e verifique no `phpinfo()` se carregou a library.

Se ainda assim não conseguir, pode tentar instalar o PEAR/PECL independente do XAMP.

```
> wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
> php go-pear.phar
> pecl install imagick
```

A partir daí segue as instruções acima, verificando o imagick.so no php.ini e reiniciando o Apache.

Comment: ./pecl install imagick
WARNING: configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/install" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading imagick-3.4.3.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
...................................................done: 245,410 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir /tmp/pear/install/imagick agora devolve isto ao escrever ./pecl install imagick

Comment: A mensagem diz para conceder permissões apropriadas para leitura e escrita nesse diretório indicado. Para descomplicar, apenas dê um `chmod -R 0777 /tmp`

Comment: problema permanece. vou adicionar detalhe a pergunta

Comment: o ficheiro php.ini encontrasse onde? e o que é para colocar la dentro?

Comment: tentei colocar a "extension=imagick.so" no ficheiro php.ini e reiniciei o apache mas não resolve.

Comment: não posso comentar nada pois sou alheio ao que está fazendo.. Eu poderia tentar ajudar se tivesse seguido as orientações.  Um problema é que por não seguir os passos descritos na resposta, vc pode ter criado 2 ou mais instalações diferentes do php no seu sistema e pode até estar editando um php.ini inválido. Há muitos motivos, tornando qualquer ajuda inviável de se responder sob o escopo do site SO-pt. Terá de resolver sozinho ou contratar um profissional. Outro meio é esperar a boa sorte para que algum profissional trabalhe de graça para resolver o seu trabalho. Boa sorte..  vai precisar.